# htaccess redirect all html files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can someone write me a rule that will redirect all requests for

```
http://www.example.com/some_page.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/some_page/
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you really want to redirect requests of `/some_page.html` to `/some_page/`:

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

But if you want to reverse (redirect requests of `/some_page/` to `/some_page.html`):

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1.html [L,R]
```

For a permanent redirect, use `R=301` instead of `R`. And for just an internal rewrite, use the rule without `R` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com$1/
```