# Redirect only HTML files?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, loops

## Part One

I want to .htaccess redirect all HTML files to the home page. I looked at this guy's question ([htaccess redirect all html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472982/htaccess-redirect-all-html-files)), and wrote this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pandamonia.us$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.pandamonia.us$  
RewriteRule .*\.html$ "http\:\/\/pandamonia\.us\/" [L]
```

but the problem is that it also redirects the homepage to itself, causing the universe to end.

[image]

So my question, is how can I redirect every HTML page that is *not* the homepage to the homepage.

## Part Two

[Exclude certain subfolders and domains in redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732275/exclude-certain-subfolders-and-domains-in-redirects)

Comment: whats that icon? do you have some plugin installed?

Comment: I used Candybar.app to set the icon. I got it from this guy on DeviantArt: http://kamikaze00x.deviantart.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `.*` to `.+` in the regexp, that should mean 'at least one character' instead of zero or more characters, so the empty string should be avoided.

Wait.  The initial '/' is included.  Try it like:

```
RewriteRule /.+\.html$ "http\:\/\/pandamonia\.us\/" [L]
```

Comment: I just put for spaces before the code line and stackoverflow did the rest.  :-)

Comment: Can you take a look at part two?  :)