# Where to place redirect in htaccess file (removing html extension)

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently attempting to redirect

www.mywebsite.com/folder.html   to

www.mywebsite.com/folder

**(I am changing webhosts, my old host used html urls and those are the ones indexed by search engines)**

I found the first part of my solution that gave me the rewrite code:
[htaccess redirect all html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472982/htaccess-redirect-all-html-files)

But I can't seem to get it to work.  This is the current code in my htaccess file:

```
     # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Here is my second attempt after the first answer to this question. (not sure if I placed it correctly):

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Here is the **Original Code** in my htaccess file:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Is there something else I need to do to get it to work?  Does it take time to work?
I wasn't sure if I should post this to the original question or start a new thread, I'm happy to move it accordingly if needed.

Thanks,

Valerie

Answer (score 0):

The default Wordpress install should already have clean urls.  Is this something outside of wordpress?

You can rewrite the .html extension with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If you still have issues, send me what your .htaccess was prior to the modification and I'll provide a more detailed example.

---

Per your update:

First, any changes to your .htaccess file will have an immediate effect on the server.  Second, how many .html files do you need to redirect?  One solution that is a bit more precise would be to have a line item for each individual url redirect.

For instance, add this to the bottom of your .htaccess file (change the file names accordingly, I based it off of your example).  You can duplicate the line for each page that needs to be redirected.

```
Redirect 301 /folder.html http://www.mywebsite.com/folder
```

Explanation:
**/folder.html** is the original location of the page (in relation to the root directory) and **http://www.mywebsite.com/folder** is the pages current location.

Comment: Thanks Msussman, I'm adding the original code to the question.